# Windows DIR listing switch to exclude files in hidden folders

Tags: windows, command-line-interface, switch

I'm trying to get a list of files from a directory excluding files in hidden folders.  With the following command, hidden folders are traversed even though I've set /A:-H to exclude hidden directories.  Is there a different switch to stop them from being traversed too?

`dir "C:\SVN" /A:-H /w /b /s`

Alternatively, for this use case I know the *name* of the hidden folders I want to exclude, so if there is a way to exclude the folders by name `("\.svn\")` that might have to suffice.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `/a:-h` switch only applies to specific items that are marked hidden, it doesn't check the attributes of any ancestors.  That is, files within a hidden folder also have to be marked as hidden themselves, otherwise `dir` will list them.  To make this work you'll need to mark all of the subitems in your `.svn` folder as hidden.

Answer (score 0):

```
dir c:\svn /a:-h /w /b /s | findstr /i /v ".svn"
```